# Should a ViewPager fragments be destroyed when activity is paused?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am wondering about proper ViewPager usage. I have an application with 2 activities. First of it is a ViewPager activity with a ListFragment. When I choose an element in list another activity starts and the main is paused of course. My question is: should the fragments in ViewPager be destroyed to save memory? If yes what is the best way to implement it? initialise and release ViewPager in onPause/onResume methods?

Comment: Can you post codes or at least what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't destroy views on pause.